# Trying to install SawMill and getting the following error:

Tags: centos6

```
[root@sawmill sawmill]# ./sawmill
./sawmill: error while loading shared libraries: libldap-2.3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Using `yum provides libldap_r-2.3.so.0` i found that the package which includes this file is: compat-openldap-2.3.43-2.el6.i686 .
After installing it i still get the error.
If i use locate, i can find the file in /usr/lib, so I tried to create a symbolic link to the file from /usr/lib to /usr/lib64 but i still get the same error.
I also tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ and LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64 but it doesn't allow me to run the sawmill installation script.
Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Edit: Installing the package you mentioned fixed the libldap file, now i'm getting stuck on the libssl file, do you know how to solve it?

```
[root@sawmill sawmill]# ldd sawmill
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe0cf7000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff5fe30e000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007ff5fe0f4000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ff5fdeda000)
        libcrypto.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.6 (0x00007ff5fdb40000)
        libldap-2.3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libldap-2.3.so.0 (0x00007ff5fd903000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff5fd6e7000)
        libssl.so.6 => not found
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007ff5fd4af000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff5fd1a9000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff5fcf25000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff5fcd0e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff5fc97e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff5fe518000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff5fc768000)
        liblber-2.3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/liblber-2.3.so.0 (0x00007ff5fc559000)
        libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007ff5fc33f000)
        libssl.so.10 => not found
        libfreebl3.so => /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007ff5fc0dc000)
[root@sawmill sawmill]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `ldd /path/to/sawmill`.  That should show you the full path where sawmill is looking for the library.

I would probably symlink from there to wherever your package manager installed it.

---

Regarding the new error, you're on a 64bit OS right?

Try installing `openldap-2.3.43-2.el6.x86_64` instead of `openldap-2.3.43-2.el6.i686`.

Comment: I've edited the question with more information, thanks for your assitance.

Answer (score 0):

The libssl.so.6 & libssl.so.10 are part of the OpenSSL package. To install:

```
yum install openssl
```

Then re-run the command below to make sure those not found errors have been resolved:

```
ldd sawmill
```

If so, re-run your install and you should be good.

To find which library belongs to which package run:

```
yum whatprovides libssl.so.6
```

-Brendan